# Allow specific IPs to call file

Tags: debian, apache2.4

I got the following configuration in my apache2.4 web server:

```
<FilesMatch "(^\.|wp-config\.php|xmlrpc\.php|(?<!robots)\.txt|(liesmich|readme)\.*)"> 
Require ip 216.151.209.64 216.151.209.127 66.135.48.128 66.135.48.255 69.174.248.128 69.174.248.255 76.74.255.0 76.74.255.127 216.151.210.0 216.151.210.127 76.74.248.128 76.74.248.255 76.74.254.0 76.74.254.127 207.198.112.0 207.198.113.255 207.198.101.0 207.198.101.127 198.181.116.0 198.181.119.255 192.0.64.0 192.0.127.255 66.155.8.0 66.155.11.255 66.155.38.0 66.155.38.255 72.233.119.192 72.233.119.255 209.15.21.0 209.15.21.255
</FilesMatch>
```

Well, if I call example.com/xmlrpc.php from a valid IP, I'm still getting 401. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your big regex in the FilesMatch requires a literal dot be present after the primary things you're matching, which looks unintentional.  I don't think you meant to escape that last ".".